# SQL Server bulk insert with format file

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert, bcp

Using SQL Server various versions 2016+

I am working on a set of import routines and need to create dynamic format files as part of new requirements handed down from above as part of a larger project.

I have an example where I can create the format file via BCP, however when I attempt to use it, the import fails

```
Msg 4866, Level 16, State 17, Line 45
The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2, Line 45
Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

This does not happen when I import the file without a format file.  The format file appears to be generated correctly, with tab delimitation and standard row terminator.

```
14.0
19
1       SQLNCHAR            8       0       "\t"   1     Command                                          Latin1_General_CI_AS
2       SQLNCHAR            2       100     "\t"   2     Source                                           Latin1_General_CI_AS
3       SQLNCHAR            8       0       "\t"   3     CompanyImportID                                  Latin1_General_CI_AS
4       SQLNCHAR            2       100     "\t"   4     AccountNo                                        Latin1_General_CI_AS
5       SQLNCHAR            2       510     "\t"   5     Profile                                          Latin1_General_CI_AS
6       SQLINT              1       4       "\t"   6     CompanyActive                                    ""
7       SQLNCHAR            2       200     "\t"   7     CompanyName                                      Latin1_General_CI_AS
8       SQLNCHAR            2       510     "\t"   8     Admin_Email_Address                              Latin1_General_CI_AS
9       SQLNCHAR            2       100     "\t"   9     PaymentMethod                                    Latin1_General_CI_AS
10      SQLINT              1       4       "\t"   10    DefaultStockLocation                             ""
11      SQLINT              1       4       "\t"   11    ChargeCompanyVAT                                 ""
12      SQLNCHAR            2       20      "\t"   12    DefaultCurrency                                  Latin1_General_CI_AS
13      SQLINT              1       4       "\t"   13    EnforcePORef                                     ""
14      SQLINT              1       4       "\t"   14    FixedDeliveryAddress                             ""
15      SQLINT              1       4       "\t"   15    SendOrderConfirmations                           ""
16      SQLNCHAR            2       100     "\t"   16    DefaultPriceCode                                 Latin1_General_CI_AS
17      SQLNCHAR            2       100     "\t"   17    SpecialPriceCode                                 Latin1_General_CI_AS
18      SQLNCHAR            2       510     "\t"   18    DivCode1                                         Latin1_General_CI_AS
19      SQLNCHAR            2       510     "\n"   19    DivCode2                                         Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

The usual advice on setting the row terminators has been followed.  Sample code for generating the format file and reading in are as follows:

```
-- Setup tables
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dba.companies

CREATE TABLE [dba].[companies] ( [Command]                [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL
,                                [Source]                 [NVARCHAR](50)  NULL
,                                [CompanyImportID]        [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL
,                                [AccountNo]              [NVARCHAR](50)  NULL
,                                [Profile]                [NVARCHAR](255) NULL
,                                [CompanyActive]          [INT]           NULL
,                                [CompanyName]            [NVARCHAR](100) NULL
,                                [Admin_Email_Address]    [NVARCHAR](255) NULL
,                                [PaymentMethod]          [NVARCHAR](50)  NULL
,                                [DefaultStockLocation]   [INT]           NULL
,                                [ChargeCompanyVAT]       [INT]           NULL
,                                [DefaultCurrency]        [NVARCHAR](10)  NULL
,                                [EnforcePORef]           [INT]           NULL
,                                [FixedDeliveryAddress]   [INT]           NULL
,                                [SendOrderConfirmations] [INT]           NULL
,                                [DefaultPriceCode]       [NVARCHAR](50)  NULL
,                                [SpecialPriceCode]       [NVARCHAR](50)  NULL
,                                [DivCode1]               [NVARCHAR](255) NULL
,                                [DivCode2]               [NVARCHAR](255) NULL )

-- Build format file
DECLARE @strSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT  @strSQL = N'EXEC xp_cmdshell ''bcp ' + DB_NAME () + N'.dba.companies format nul -n -f "c:\examples\1_Companies-OK.fmt" -t "\t" -r "0x0a" -T'''
EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = @strSQL

-- Read without format file - works fine
BULK INSERT dba.companies
FROM 'c:\examples\1_Companies-OK.txt'
WITH ( FIRSTROW = 2
,      ERRORFILE = 'c:\examples\1_Companies-OK_errors.txt'
,      FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t'
,      ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
,      CODEPAGE = 65001 )

SELECT  *
  FROM  dba.companies

GO

-- Read with format file - unexpected EOF
BULK INSERT dba.companies
FROM 'c:\examples\1_Companies-OK.txt'
WITH ( FIRSTROW = 2
,      ERRORFILE = 'c:\examples\1_Companies-OK_errors.txt'
,      FORMATFILE = 'c:\examples\1_Companies-OK.fmt'   
,      CODEPAGE = 65001 )

SELECT  *
  FROM  dba.companies
```

I have also tried using the XML format files, i.e.

```
bcp LatestCode.dba.companies format nul -n -f "c:\examples\1_Companies-OK.fmt" -x -r "0x0a" -T
```

with that however it generates a seperate line at the very end of the record definition without an ID field which bulk insert registers as being a required attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="8" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="8" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="510" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="NativePrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="1"/>
  <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="200" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="8" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="510" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="9" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="10" xsi:type="NativePrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="1"/>
  <FIELD ID="11" xsi:type="NativePrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="1"/>
  <FIELD ID="12" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="20" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="13" xsi:type="NativePrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="1"/>
  <FIELD ID="14" xsi:type="NativePrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="1"/>
  <FIELD ID="15" xsi:type="NativePrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="1"/>
  <FIELD ID="16" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="17" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="18" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="510" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="19" xsi:type="NCharPrefix" PREFIX_LENGTH="2" MAX_LENGTH="510" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD xsi:type="NCharTerm" TERMINATOR="\n" MAX_LENGTH="2" COLLATION="Latin1_General_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Command" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Source" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="CompanyImportID" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="AccountNo" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="Profile" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="CompanyActive" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="CompanyName" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="8" NAME="Admin_Email_Address" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="9" NAME="PaymentMethod" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="10" NAME="DefaultStockLocation" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="11" NAME="ChargeCompanyVAT" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="12" NAME="DefaultCurrency" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="13" NAME="EnforcePORef" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="14" NAME="FixedDeliveryAddress" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="15" NAME="SendOrderConfirmations" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="16" NAME="DefaultPriceCode" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="17" NAME="SpecialPriceCode" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="18" NAME="DivCode1" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="19" NAME="DivCode2" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

I will try and link to data file too if I can find a way.

Any advice greatfully received.

Comment: I've found it's easier (unusually) to use the XML format file type, never needed bcp I just dynamically generate the required content and write it to text file. Check your row terminator  it can vary depending on the file source and encoding eg \r\n, and check the correct code page is used. You could also test easier using openrowset to just read the file.

Comment: You have specified a prefix length on each column, they should have all been 0.

Comment: @Charlieface  Those values were inserted by BCP rather than something I manually entered.  Although I have tried zeroing them, and unfortunately this then leads to ther errors.

Comment: @Stu I tried the XML format too.  Had issues with that though in specifying I'll update the question with the XML issue.